# Serializing Chess Games

Tags: complexity-theory

This is an open question I have been thinking about lately. Let's say we are black player and we play two "harmless" moves A and B. We assume it won't change anything if we play A - B or B - A. So all chess games having the exact same position and with an option A - B or B - A could end up the same. So the question is: Can chess moves be serialized like transactions in databases?

So could we compress the chess games based on similarities and classify them? For example using a bottom-up approach where we start with the most simple positions. We figure out the similarities when there is only two kings and one black rook, then we reuse those simple games in the more complex ones having the exact position …

Using that new technique, could we theoretically reduce the number of possible chess games to a "lower" upper bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most chess engines already use a technique like this: they use [transposition tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_table) to remember positions that have already been evaluated.  Since A-B and B-A both lead to the same position, during search that position will only be evaluated once and then its evaluation will be remembered, rather than evaluating the same position twice.

The sheer number of possible positions is still ridiculously large, so there is no way to enumerate them all in any reasonable amount of time.  Instead, chess engines use heuristics and search techniques to identify which positions are promising and worth examining in detail, and prune the search space so they don't have to examine all possible positions.  Transposition tables don't solve this problem.

---

Related: Model checking uses [partial order reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_order_reduction), which addresses a somewhat similar problem, though there are also important differences.